# Unable to execute Lambda in Async mode via API Gateway POST request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Why currently there no way to execute AWS Lambda in asynchronous mode via Gateway API without involving intermediary Lambda just for calling invoke() method?

Even if i add integration like this:

```
r = client.put_integration(
    restApiId=rest_api_id,
    resourceId=resource_id,
    httpMethod='POST',
    type='AWS',
    integrationHttpMethod='POST',
    uri=uri,
    requestParameters={
        'integration.request.header.X-Amz-Invocation-Type': "'Event'",
        'integration.request.header.Invocation-Type': "'Event'"
    }
)
```

It still executed synchronously...
Are there some platform limitation or so?

Comment: From the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html "If your API makes asynchronous calls to Lambda functions, you must use the AWS Service Proxy integration type". Are you using Service Proxy integration?

Comment: Is your goal to respond to the request and then continue doing work afterwards? If so then yes, you would need to invoke a separate lambda function from inside you handler.

Comment: @idbehold I know about such solution, and it works well, but i don't want to use extra function call.
@MarkB There no such type as `AWS Service Proxy` defined as valid type here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.put_integration
BTW, it seems i manage to start Lambda function execution in async mode now. It's just work, without any changes. Not sure, what cause it not to work same way before.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example Swagger document which you can switch invocation type to Lambda function. I guess you already got how to map the header to trigger the different invocation types, but I think you might forget to deploy the API.

### Swagger

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "2016-02-11T22:00:31Z",
    "title": "LambdaAsync"
  },
  "host": "<placeholder>",
  "basePath": "<placeholder>",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "X-Amz-Invocation-Type",
            "in": "header",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "httpMethod": "POST",
          "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<account>:function:<function_name>/invocations?Qualifier=$LATEST",
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200"
            }
          },
          "requestParameters": {
            "integration.request.header.X-Amz-Invocation-Type": "method.request.header.X-Amz-Invocation-Type"
          },
          "type": "aws"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Empty": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Empty Schema"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As i already defined `'integration.request.header.X-Amz-Invocation-Type': "'Event'",` there no need to send extra header data, or use header mapping.
As i pointed earlier it seems to work properly now, without any extra changes.