# how to make get LogResult of AWS Lambda with API gateway?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make each call to lambda to log the billed duration, to track the cost of using lambda.

When you invoke lambda with SDK or CLI, you could easily get the LogResult by just adding the parameter `LogType: tail`

Then you get the LogResult as a part of Response, where you can extract the billed duration.

Now, I was trying to do similar thing when we invoke lambda through API Gateway.

How could I get the LogResult and BilledDuration in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In API Gateway you'll have to follow the API reference to build the raw HTTP request with the 'AWS Service' integration type.

Here is [an example for setting a different invocation parameter `X-Amz-Invocation-Type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564597/unable-to-execute-lambda-in-async-mode-via-api-gateway-post-request) that includes a CLI call to create the integration, and also a swagger example.

In your case, `X-Amz-Log-Type` is configured in the same way as a parameter called `integration.request.header.X-Amz-Log-Type`.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "2016-02-11T22:00:31Z",
    "title": "LambdaAsync"
  },
  "host": "<placeholder>",
  "basePath": "<placeholder>",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
          "httpMethod": "POST",
          "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<account>:function:<function_name>/invocations?Qualifier=$LATEST",
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200"
            }
          },
          "requestParameters": {
            "integration.request.header.X-Amz-Log-Type": "'tail'"
          },
          "type": "aws"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Empty": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Empty Schema"
    }
  }
}
```